# Does site structure/URL structure impact SEO?

Tags: seo, google, google-search-console, google-search, web-crawlers

We would like to change the following URLs as follows:
(old versions to the left, being changed to new versions on the right)

1. `www.ex.com/xxx/full-seo-term` -> `www.ex.com/half-seo-term1/half-seo-term2` - *leaving out random keywords and instead only having seo phrases*
2. `www.ex.com/seo-word/seo-word` -> `www.ex.com/seo-phrase/seo-phrase/` *Replacing seo words with seo phrases at all levels*
3. `www.ex.com/seo-word/seo-word/seo-phrase/` -> `www.ex.com/seo-phrase/seo-phrase` *reducing number of levels in site structure and keeping seo phrases early*
4. `www.ex.com/*` *having the full website in only one level below the domain*

Answer (score 2):

We've talked about this practice here a lot of time. URL structure is important thing, so I'm just going to put you a picture so you can see clearly what's the great structure of URL.

[image]

Comment: Nice clear graphic! This addresses readability very well which influences CTR. A very important aspect.